# How to use ? question mark in url

Tags: php, url

i have a url  ,

http://mywebsite/how to do that? and that/54

encoded URL using `urlencode()`

http://mywebsite/how+to+do+that%3F+and+that/54

Now if i try to share this link using twitter or in some other way i use this link

then decoded url will appear,

http://mywebsite/how to do that? and that/54

And now if someone click on this link it will have totally different meaning because `?` is a reserved character,( and `and that` would be seen as query string)   and this url would have completelly different meaning.

So I can't able to share this link using twitter , what can i do ?

Comment: What do you mean by "will appear"? Such link clearly violates the URL syntax, so where should it appear? Why? Actually what you describe exactly is _why_ url tokens need to be encoded.

Comment: so how can i share a link with spaces ? @arkascha

Comment: I think you should read about how to make proper urls that are SEO friendly: https://moz.com/learn/seo/url . You just cannot create urls that contain punctuation etc...

Comment: By encoding it correctly.

Comment: %20 will be translated to a space character

Comment: Just taka a look at the URL for this page: `when-a-encoded-url-is-decoded-it-does-not-point-to-the-same-address-anymore` and compare it to the Title of your question: That is proper SEO optimizing for URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `urlencode()` for twitter. Share it directly, it will work.or try with rawurlencode()

Comment: still it does not work

Comment: @beginner can you check it now